# How to create a driver for Linux from within Windows?

Tags: drivers

I found a wonderful tutorial on how to install my driver [here](http://furiouspurpose.me/linux-and-the-wna3100-wireless-adapter/) but I quickly ran into a problem. Let me explain the problem i am facing. I want to install a Linux distro (still looking into different distros) on my machine. From my past painful experiences, I know that I need to install drivers separately for the wireless adapter to work. Yet in order to get the tools to convert my driver I need an internet connection. Sadly no other computer in my house has Linux on it for me to do this and since everyone in my house is scared that I'm going to break their computer (past experience makes this understandable) using a LiveCD is unheard of. I've come to the conclusion that I would most likely need to get Ndiswrapper on my Windows machine convert the driver from there and then store it in the drive somehow so I can access it later. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your wireless card model, it might already have a stable driver ;-(

Comment: The link gives it to you but it is the WNA3100.

Comment: The manufacturer is Netgear.

Comment: Have you considered using a VM (VirtualBox for instance) to get a working Linux system on one of your Windows machines? It's rather easy, nothing to be worried about in terms of breaking the Windows install.

Comment: @Mat That was my fallout plan. While VM is somewhat easy it takes time to set up and I was hoping there was just like an NDiswrapper for windows or something. If noone ends up answering I'll have to resort to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't need to extract the drivers from your Windows install. Provided you can find your device in this list:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page

... you'll simply need to follow the procedure to obtain the Windows drivers here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper#Downloading_Windows_Drivers

The Netgear WNA3100 does have a page: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Netgear_WNA3100

Comment: Is the sourceforge one already converted?

Comment: You sir. Are my savior.

Comment: ndiswrapper does some _very_ dodgy things, that just work most of the time by sheer luck. Be on the lookout for native Linux drivers, or even compiling your own kernel to use staging drivers. Check at [Linux wireless](http://linuxwireless.org) for the state of support for your card.

Comment: @Frederik Deweerdt thank you I have mostly the same issue concerning drivers support; but the problem I faced is Debian Wheezy says my display is "Unknown"... So can ndiswrapper help me to install intel graphics hd videocard driver for example or it is for wifi only?

Comment: @user592704 unfortunately, that's wiki only, as far as i know

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to get whatever you need downloaded under Windows. It might be a bit tricky to find out what "automatized installation procedures" grab and how they do it, but if it isn't obvious perhaps a Google search with the exact card version gives step by step instructions. Just be careful with "practical joker" instructions, or just misguided people who don't know what they are suggesting.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but Netgear seems to have their own little way of doing things. They have a whole fairly nice GUI where you can select all the networks and such. It's a lot like what Windows does except less automated, more annoying because Windows does it better and gets confused. And a good deal of other stuff.